# Json do return -1 instead of the values from the stored procedure

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

This is the code for the **view** where results should be displayed using Ajax form. When I generate the results, I get `-1`. However I get the desired results in form of columns in SQL server when I execute the stored procedure

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function generateStatement() {

        var member_number = $('#member').val();
        var firstDate = $('#start_date').val();
        var secondDate = $('#end_date').val();

        const url = '/memberbalances/getSummary_statement';

        $.getJSON(url, { member_number, firstDate, secondDate},function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
                console.log(entry);


                })
            })

    }
</script>
```

This is the **controller** code, I am using dapper Orm to map the query to the database.
When I click the button to generate the results, I get `-1` 
instead of values in the column which I get when I execute the stored procedure in the SQL server

```
[Authorize]
public JsonResult getSummary_statement(string member_number,string firstDate,string secondDate)
{
    try
    {
        using (sqlConnection)
        {


           DateTime startDate= Convert.ToDateTime(firstDate);

           DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(secondDate);


            var summary_statement = sqlConnection.Execute("get_summary_memberStatement",
                new
                {
                    member_number,startDate,endDate
                },commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return Json(summary_statement,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used `break-point` to check if it goes into `catch` block or not?

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz yes I have used... It's just going to return Json method

Comment: Please update your question and include what is the content of `summary_statement` before you return it. Is it a valid json string? is it "-1"? Is it something else?

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz what do you mean the content of the summary_statement before I return?

Comment: Never mind. Before `return Json(summary_statement,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` add `var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(summary_statement);`. Place a break-point and see the contents of `jsonString` and finally `return Json(jsonString,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz It  still gives "-1" as well. No exception caught.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the Controller code and am getting the desired results now..I have changed like nothing really.

```
[Authorize]
public JsonResult getSummary_statement(string member_number, string firstDate, string secondDate)
{
    try
    {
        using (sqlConnection)
        {
            DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(firstDate);

            DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(secondDate);
            var summary_statement = sqlConnection.Query
                ("get_summary_memberStatement", new {
                    member_number,
                    startDate,
                    endDate
                }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return Json(summary_statement, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```